# Clarification for inverse trigonometric fuctions.

Tags: trigonometry, notation

Since sin⁻¹(x) means the inverse of sin(x), also written as arcsin(x), how would you write 1/sin(x)?
Since sin²(x) actually does mean sin(x) * sin(x), can you write 1/(sinx *sinx) as sin⁻²(x)?

Comment: You can write $1/\sin x$ as $\text{cosec}\,x$.

Comment: It is $$\csc(x)=\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$$

Comment: And it is $$\frac{1}{\sin(x)\sin(x)}=\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}=\sin^{-2}(x)$$

Comment: Normally I use $\arcsin(x)$ for inverse functions, I prefer this notation

Comment: This is why $\sin^{-1}{(x)}$ is disliked by many mathematicians for its use to describe $\arcsin{(x)}$.

Comment: @PeterForeman I like $\sin^{-1}x$. I don't like $\sin^2 x$, since that should be $\sin(\sin x)$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Do you really use $\sin^{-2}x$ in your writings?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Do you think that $\sin^{-2}{(x)}$ should mean $\arcsin{(\arcsin{(x)})}$?

Comment: @PeterForeman That makes sense! Do you agree with Dr.S.G. about what it should be?

Comment: I believe the only ambiguity is when it comes to what $\sin^{-1}{(x)}$ means. I believe that the notation $\sin^n{(x)}$ should be used to represent $(\sin{(x)})^n$, but that is just my (and Wolfram: Alphas) opinion.